# How to import products from xlsx file in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento

I have products in .XLSX files and want to import in Magento. So please tell me how can I import files OR do I need to change file format to .CSV ?
I tried to change format in .CSV but it gives error that **SKU is undefined, it can't import**

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is to export the product template in magento. 
Then, import / organize the product fields from your .XLSX into Magento's CSV Template.
Save it as .CSV and you can now import the products.

This is the Best practice when importing files into magento.

Comment: Thanks Mike for reply, Please can you describe how to export the product template in magneto? Because ionly exported products from export option and dataflow only.  Thanks

Comment: hello Mike, are you there ? Or anyone can help me ?

Comment: In order to export products, go to:
1. System -> Import/Export -> Export
2. Under Export Settings, 
Entity Type: Products
Export File Format: CSV
3. Then, at the bottom of the page, click continue.
4. Done. you can now update / insert new products. 
5. Last, Import the updated file.